# Вордпресс произвольные поля выводит с ошибкой

Tags: php, wordpress

есть произвольное поле с изображением 
путь к изображению http://sgtr.gr.ru/newdiz/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/3ddigitalart-stand-alone-savers-wallpapers-screen-3d-scene-65433.jpg
а выводит

```
<div class="sl1 slide-wrapper" style="background-image:url(\" http:="" sgtr.gr.ru="" newdiz="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2017="" 09="" landscape-images-scenic-dream-moon-185122.jpg\");"="">
```

подозреваю что какая-то функция слеши режет
Вывожу так

```
    $vddx3 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-slidimg');

echo '
       <div class="slide-box w-slide">
          <div class="sl1 slide-wrapper" style="background-image:url("';

echo    $vddx3[0];




echo'");">
```

Comment: urlencode перед выводом привело путь в формат http%3a%2f%2fsgtr.gr.ru%2fnewdiz%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2017%2f09%2fstarry-night-image-wallpapers-back-45760-300x169.jpg");"

Comment: сочетание urldecode(UrlEncode($url)) дает тот же результат. какая-то функция в вордпрессе тупо режет слэши, делая из них =""

Comment: что выдает var_dump($vddx3)?

Comment: @KAGG Изменил код (через изображение поста)                      
$thumbnail_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'medium' ); 

 
echo '
       <div class="slide-box w-slide">
          <div class="sl1 slide-wrapper" style="background-image:url("'.var_dump($thumbnail_attributes[0]).'");">
                   
выдало
<div class="sl1 slide-wrapper" style="background-image:url(" ");"="">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   urldecode ($vddx3[0]);?>
```

Спасёт ситуацию.

Comment: <div class="sl1 slide-wrapper" style="background-image:url(" http:="" sgtr.gr.ru="" newdiz="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2017="" 09="" 3dlandscape-3ddigitalart-blue-night-savers-wallpapers-screen-65432-300x169.jpg");"="">
не спасло

Comment: Я лично проверил. Взял тот урл что у вас выходит и прогнал через метод.

Comment: Давайте сделаем так

`$vddx3 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-slidimg');
echo '
       <div class="slide-box w-slide">
          <div class="sl1 slide-wrapper" style="background-image:url(\'';
echo    urldecode($vddx3[0]);
echo'\');">`

Comment: Не знаю, как Вы это сделали, но оно заработало! Спасибо огромное!